# Bootstrap Checkbox always return on

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am using bootstrap checkbox. the code for getting value and checkbox is bellow

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      
      var mycheckboxNewVal;
      
      var mycheckboxVal = $('#mycheckbox').val();
      
      if(mycheckboxVal == 'on')
        {
          mycheckboxNewVal==1;
        }
      else
        {
          mycheckboxNewVal==0;
        }
          
      alert("mycheckboxNewVal :"+mycheckboxNewVal);

       
      
    });
```

```html
    <div class="col-sm-1-5"><label class="control-label" for="pwd">Check Box </label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <span class="button-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked id="mycheckbox"/>
      <button type="button" class="btn-chk" data-color="success"></button>
     </span>
    </div>
```

When I do 'alert("mycheckboxNewVal :"+mycheckboxNewVal);' I always get value 1.

Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the `checked` one:

```
$('#mycheckbox:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't check for the value in case of `checkbox`, check for the `checked` property of checkbox.

```
  var mycheckboxVal = $('#mycheckbox')[0].checked;

  if(mycheckboxVal)
    {
      // Checkbox is checked.
      mycheckboxNewVal==1;
    }
  else
    {
      mycheckboxNewVal==0;
    }
```